# How to detect an empty file in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, fstream

I am trying to use eof and peek but both seems not to give me the right answer.

```
if (inputFile.fail()) //check for file open failure
{
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    cout << "Note that the program will halt" << endl;//error prompt
}

else if (inputFile.eof())
{
    cout << "File is empty" << endl;
    cout << "Note that program will halt" << endl; // error prompt
}
else
{
    //run the file
}
```

it cannot detect any empty file using this method. If i use inputFile.peek instead of eof it would make my good files as empty files.

Comment: How are you using `peek()`? The EOF flag is only set after a read reached the end of the file, by the way.

Comment: Whoops again a missed this duplicate, there's hardly any question these days which ain't has any duplicate in one way or the other

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `peek` like following

```
if ( inputFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof() )
{
   // Empty File

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would open the file at the end and see what that position is using `tellg()`:

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile", std::ios::ate); // std::ios::ate means open at end

if(ifs.tellg() == 0)
{
    // file is empty
}
```

The function `tellg()` returns the read (get) position of the file and we opened the file with the read (get) position at the end using `std::ios::ate`. So if `tellg()` returns `0` it must be empty.

**Update:** From `C++17` onward you can use [std::filesyatem::file_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size):

```
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem; // for readability

// ...

if(fs::file_size(myfile) == 0)
{
    // file is empty
}
```

**Note:** Some compilers already support the `<filesystem>` library as a [Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) (eg, GCC v5.3).

Answer (score 2):

If "empty" means that the length of the file is zero (i.e. no characters at all) then just find the length of the file and see if it's zero:

```
inputFile.seekg (0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();

if (length == 0)
{
    // do your error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream fin("test.txt");
if (inputFile.fail()) //check for file open failure
{
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    cout << "Note that the program will halt" << endl;//error prompt
}
int flag=0;
while(!fin.eof())
{
char ch=(char)fin.get();
flag++;
break;
}
if (flag>0)
cout << "File is not empty" << endl;
else
cout << "File is empty" << endl;
```